# All React Router routes except the root ("/") respond with a 401 Unauthorized Error

Tags: networking, react-router, authorization

I recently learned React Router and am working to refactor over a project that used hash-routing to use React Router's `BrowserRouter` instead. When I went to test my first route, I received a 401 Unauthorized Error. Entering any text into the URL bar after localhost:3000/ causes this error, regardless of whether the `Route` exists in my `app.jsx` file. Leaving the back part of the URL off (localhost:3000) or only adding a slash (localhost:3000/) loads in whatever page I have setup in the `<Route path="/" element={ <ElementToRender /> }` /> just fine.

What I **think** is the problem:

I think the `index.html` file isn't being served to my browser. For some reason, there's an authentication wall preventing the browser from grabbing the file.

Things I've Tried:

1. Switching to the HashRouter fixes the problem. I can't figure out why this is.
2. Investigating the Network Tab. I've looked at successful requests from a previous project where I played around with React Router, and couldn't find anything strange in the Network Request tab. Here's the information for the failed request.

Request URL: http://localhost:3000/register
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Connection: keep-alive
content-length: 35
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 13 Mar 2023 18:16:02 GMT
ETag: W/"23-NPT3XhyBFeUKvS1KZ/jc0dymZSA"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: connect.sid=s%3AeT5IKOFT3GsMAeTlpNuEnbP5vy3beQXK.mucLgb13MH5y0YQRLefsHn5AT02no8BVUQukNPwrUa8
Host: localhost:3000
If-Modified-Since: Mon, 13 Mar 2023 16:23:19 GMT
If-None-Match: W/"281-186dbc88f8a"
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="110", "Not A(Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="110"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

3. Removing all of the extra code in my `app.jsx` component except for the `Routes` and `Route` components. I thought context or my old user auth might be causing the issue, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I've been working on this / troubleshooting for a week or so -- if you have any help or ideas about why I'm getting the 401 authorization error -- I'm up to try anything. The link to my repo is https://github.com/cam-peck/runningfuze. Thanks so much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a `HashRouter` all page requests to the server go to the same URL, the server ignores the hash as it's not necessary to serve a document.

Examples `"https://www.example.com/subdomain/#/"` or `"https://www.example.com/subdomain/#/register"`, all page requests to the server are at `"https://www.example.com/subdomain/"` and the app bundle is returned and the the React app handles routing/rendering the appropriate page via the hash, e.g. `"/"` or `"/register"`.

This is different from when you are using a `BrowserRouter` and the URL is `"https://www.example.com/subdomain/"` or `"https://www.example.com/subdomain/register"`. In the case of the latter the browser makes a request to the server for a document at `"/subdomain/register"`.

> Switching to the HashRouter fixes the problem. I can't figure out why
> this is.

Switching back to a `HashRouter` fixes the issue for the reason explained above.

If you want, or need, to switch to and use a non-hash router then the server should be configured to redirect/serve the root `index.html` file for ***all*** page requests into the React app it's hosting. In other words, if the browser requests `"https://www.example.com/subdomain/register"` the server should return the index.html file it's hosting at `"https://www.example.com/subdomain"` and allow the React app to load and match the URL path to the appropriate route it is rendering, e.g. `"/register"`.

Each server/hosting environment is different and may very likely require very specific setups/configurations. See the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to gather a broad sense of the different ways a React app may be hosted/served. There is perhaps already a section specific to your use case/needs.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer -- that makes sense! Using the deployment docs you linked I was able to get the BrowserRouter working.